# I cant get the user id that is in the payload from my middleware in my get request

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

Hello I use jwt with node and express and mongoose and I made a register API that works here is the code    `jwt.sign({ payload, }, process.env.jwtSecret, { expiresIn: '999h' }, (err, token) => { console.log(token) });`

this is working but I have an auth middleware where I get the token from x-auth-token in headers i think this is working but I am not sure here is the code:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

    //get the token 
    const token = req.header("x-auth-token");

    //check if not token 
    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({ msg: "No token, authorization denied" });
    }

    //verify token 
    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "jwttokensecret22030293020003023");

        req.user = decoded.user;
        next()

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(401).json({ msg: "Token is not valid" })
    }


}
```

and now I want to get the user it to an protected route the protected route works like If i delete the token from headers i cant get the token but i want to get the user id from req.user and i can't i get undefined here is the code:

```
router.get('/testauth', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.user.id)

        res.json(req.user)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
        res.status(500).send("Server error")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

solved i had the variable req.user = decoded.user instead of decoded.payload.id thanks